# How to use the Azure IoT Hub node on ROS?

Tags: python, c++, ros, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I'm making a project combining robotics and cloud computing.
Beginning simply, I currently use a raspberry py with Ubuntu and ROS Kinectic, controlling an arduino with some servomotors and sensors. In order to monitor the sensors data, I want to connect my Raspberry to Microsoft Azure Cloud using the Python SDK for Azure IoT Hub.

This could be done by creating a node that subscribes to the "sensors" topics and sends the data received to Azure IoT Hub.

I found an Azure IoT HuB node provided on Github but can't figure out how to use it or find documentation on it: https://github.com/microsoft/ros_azure_iothub

I wonder if someone has some advice/experience about this node? any documentation?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: In the GitHub repository that you have linked there are readme.md files containing basic instructions and links for further reading.

Comment: Have you tired this: https://github.com/microsoft/ros_azure_iothub/blob/kinetic-devel/roscpp_azure_iothub/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to do to connect your raspberry pi to Azure IOT hub using python

1) Setup your PI

For setup , you can use this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) to enable SSH on your pi.

Enable I2C on your Pi
Use below link to enable I2C.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

2) Connect your sensor with your PI

3) Download and setup referenced modules

1. Clone the client application to local:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git-core
   ```

   git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-python-raspberrypi-client-app.git

Because the Azure IoT SDKs for Python are wrappers on top of the [SDKs for C][azure-iot-sdk-c], you will need to compile the C libraries if you want or need to generate the Python libraries from source code.

```
cd ./iot-hub-python-raspberrypi-client-app
   sudo chmod u+x setup.sh
   sudo ./setup.sh
```

In the above script, we run ./setup.sh without parameter, so the shell will automatically detect and use the version of python installed (Search sequence 2.7->3.4->3.5). Alternatively, you can use a parameter to specify the python version which you want to use like this: sudo ./setup.sh [--python-version|-p] [2.7|3.4|3.5]

```
Known build issues:

1.) On building the Python client library (`iothub_client.so`) on Linux devices that have less than **1GB** RAM, you may see build getting **stuck** at **98%** while building `iothub_client_python.cpp` as shown below

``[ 98%] Building CXX object python/src/CMakeFiles/iothub_client_python.dir/iothub_client_python.cpp.o``

If you run into this issue, check the **memory consumption** of the device using `free -m command` in another terminal window during that time. If you are running out of memory while compiling iothub_client_python.cpp file, you may have to temporarily increase the **swap space** to get more available memory to successfully build the Python client side device SDK library.
```

You can refer the sample code [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-python-raspberrypi-client-app).

Hope it helps.